# What does scanning Pokémon's QR codes do?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I recently came across an image dump of all shiny/non-shiny Pokémon's QR codes. Before I start scanning away, I'd like to know what benefit all these codes will get me. What does scanning the QR codes for Pokémon do?

Comment: Scanning a QR code reads the code as a series of lines of either binary or hexadecimal data depending on whether it is a color or non-color system of encoding QR codes. Said data is then interpreted appropriately.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck that has nothing to do with Pokémon though. I was asking how it affected the game.

Comment: "What does scanning QR codes do?". I know programming. It felt wrong for me to not at least try to answer the question in the way I read it from the ad on the stack exchange site and give a little information for you. :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) It adds them to your Pokédex as "Seen" Pokémon, so you can check the map for their catch locations (and I think activates the "This move will be Super effective" / "Effective" / "Not very effective" message in the battle screen?)

2) After scanning ten codes, you can activate the "Island Scan" feature, which spawns a rare (in Alola) Pokémon somewhere on the island you are currently on for 60 minutes.

You can scan ten codes a day, after which it slowly recharges over time.

Comment: The last I read was that the scans regenerate at a rate of 1 every 2 hours.

Comment: It also adds the specific sprite to your Pokedex. So even if you have already caught some Pokemon and scan the QR code for a different sprite (shiny, different Forme, gender differences), that sprite will be added to its Pokedex entry.

Answer (score 5):

Scanning a Pokémon's QR code will register you as having seen it, in your Pokédex.

As an added benefit registering 10 Pokémon, even if you have seen them before enables you to perform an [Island Scan](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/dailyevent.shtml) for rare Pokémon. These Pokémon vary by day of the week and by island, for a total of 28 different Pokémon. They are not otherwise obtainable in game. The scanned Pokémon will appear at a random location on your current island, and you will only get a single encounter with it.

You can scan an additional Pokémon every 2 hours, and store up to 10 scans in total.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the above answers, [**there are also special event QR codes that can award event Pokémon.**](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_QR_Code_in-game_event_Pok%C3%A9mon_in_Generation_VII)